# How to use jetty RewriteRegexRule to modify the query string of a URL

Tags: jetty, url-rewriting

Im trying to use the url rewriting functionality in Jetty to implement search friendly URLs. The application previously ran on IIS using an isapi dll to perform URL rewriting. In that context it would take the path info an insert it as a query string parameter.

When I try to do that same thing in jetty I get a 404. If I leave out the query string then the rewrite works, but it is missing critical information. Is there a setting on RewriteRegexRule to make it reprocess the querystring?

An non working example would be

```
<Call name="addRule">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteRegexRule">
      <Set name="regex">(/.*)</Set>
      <Set name="replacement">/index.cfm?path=$1</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

Remove the ? and subsequent query string and it works.

Comment: Been looking at this too, but also failing to find a solution. The [RewriteRegexRule code](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/xref/org/eclipse/jetty/rewrite/handler/RewriteRegexRule.html) explicitly supports query string in the replacement so I can only guess there's a bug either in the [Request](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/xref/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Request.html) class. :/

Comment: Looks like the source I was looking at is for Jetty 8.1 - there's a [fixed bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=370081) for this (not visible when searching; only appeared when I went to report a new bug), and after tracking down the [related commit](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/commit/cacc5aefa214fc3eae05eb93d964863bb71198a0) (not linked from bug report; bugzilla sucks) it shows that the new code is what I was looking at earlier, and they are what hopefully fixes things.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell it is not possible to modify the querystring when performing a rewrite with Jetty. It is possible when doing a redirect, but that doesnt meet my requirements.

An alternative is the Tuckey url rewrite filter. It works, but form data is lost when using it on Jetty.

In the end I have moved to Glassfish, on which the Tuckey filter works well.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRegexRule was buggy prior to Jetty 8.1 stopping query strings from working.

Here are the steps I took in order to upgrade my Jetty 7 setup:

1) Download a copy of Jetty 8.1.5 and extract to suitable location.

2) Copy across config from existing Jetty 7 install

3) Receive stupid error `java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlParser$Node`

4) Find [mailing list thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg02404.html) identifying problem as missing DOCTYPE in contexts configs.

5) Place `<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">` after `<?xml...` line before `<Context...` line.

6) Copy appropriate jar files for Railo CFML Servlet into `lib/ext` directory.

7) Receive cryptic error: `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lo
rg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/la`

8) Disable Railo's `lib/ext/slf4j-api.jar` which apparently conflicts with something Jetty uses.

9) Jetty starts but refuses to handle context due to another error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept`

10) Look for jar related to `org.objectweb.asm`; find it in `lib/annotations`; remember seeing setting related to annotations in start.ini; disable annotations.

11) Jetty finally starts succesfully and enables the context.

12) Stop Jetty, restore original rewrite rule, restart; it works!

Now to see about getting [per-context rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942544/can-you-assign-per-web-app-jetty-rewrite-xml-files-in-jetty) working...