# Can you assign per web app jetty-rewrite.xml files in Jetty?

Tags: jetty, url-rewriting

Is there a way per web app / context to specify a rewrite file just for that particular webapp? The only way I see this currently working is via the command line when you start it. I was thinking perhaps a setting in the override.xml file or even in the context xml file.

Comment: There might be something relating to doing this at https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-rewrite/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/rewrite/handler/RewriteHandler.java but it's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you use context.xml deployables you can integrate the RewriteHandler rules into the app specific context xml.

Example: this is a replacement context.xml of the `${jetty.home}/contexts/test.xml` found in the jetty-distribution.  It adds a rule that simply adds a cookie (visited=yes) on the response for all requests.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Set name="handler">
    <New id="Rewrite" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler">
      <Set name="handler">
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
          <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
          <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/test.war</Set>
          <Set name="extractWAR">true</Set>
          <Set name="copyWebDir">false</Set>
          <Set name="defaultsDescriptor"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/webdefault.xml</Set>
          <Set name="overrideDescriptor"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/contexts/test.d/override-web.xml</Set>
        </New>
      </Set>
      <Set name="rewriteRequestURI">true</Set>
      <Set name="rewritePathInfo">false</Set>
      <Set name="originalPathAttribute">requestedPath</Set>

      <!-- add a cookie to each path visited -->
      <Call name="addRule">
        <Arg>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.CookiePatternRule">
            <Set name="pattern">/*</Set>
            <Set name="name">visited</Set>
            <Set name="value">yes</Set>
          </New>
        </Arg>
      </Call>
     </New>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

To verify that this rule works, start jetty, goto `http://localhost:8080/` and then use the "Sessions" test component, you'll see that `visited=true` will be visible as a cookie at the top.

Comment: _"If you use context.xml deployables"_ - I don't know what that means, but I have each individual context defined in `{jetty}/contexts/{name}.xml` - I do not have a test.xml or any test components.

Comment: I attempted to apply this example to an existing context config (by transferring the Set commands from the WebAppContext Configure to the respective New tag in your example), but that resulted in a StackOverflowError at `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.setAttribute(Dispatcher.java:410)` ([full trace](http://pastebin.com/vZEvmDRj)) when trying to access `/` - it looks like it works (includes set-cookie header with response) when visiting a specific file.

Comment: I don't know if this is a Jetty bug, or due to some mis-configuration or something else? An explanation of how this handler wrapping stuff works would probably be useful. (Trying to debug the issue, I took the top-level contextPath out - it didn't appear to change anything, so I'm wondering if it's needed?)

Comment: This example works, however it doesn't actually allow you to redirect or rewrite, it appears as though this rewrite/redirect is being done AFTER the normal context handling, resulting in a `Not Found` 404 error after the rewrite. Setting a cookie or header works fine.